# Accessing ag-grid column visibility event completion

Tags: ag-grid

we are using ag-grid (v17.1) with angular in our project. We (need to display) displaying 160+ at a time in grid. On Select All / Deselect All, in tool panel, it takes around 15-20 seconds to show/hide the columns. I wanted to show overlay spinner for such event. Overriding the column visibility event does not provide us the exact time, when the ag-grid has completed with rendering the columns. I wanted clarification on below questions.

1. How can we identify if ag-grid has completed rendering columns?
2. Can we override tool panel and customize it? (I checked on ag-grid documentation and could not find a way to override tool panel)

Answer (score 0):

`onGridReady` function indicates that the init process is done.

> [gridReady](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#miscellaneous) :  ag-Grid has **initialised**.

Next, if you need data loading identification you can handle it by yourself via [overlays](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-overlays/)

```
// show 'loading' overlay
gridOptions.api.showLoadingOverlay()

// show 'no rows' overlay
gridOptions.api.showNoRowsOverlay()

// clear all overlays
gridOptions.api.hideOverlay()
```

Also to override default `overlays` you can define it inside `gridOptions` as `overlayLoadingTemplate` and `overlayNoRowsTemplate`.

`Tool panel` customization available from [19.0 version](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/?fixVersion=19.0.0)

> The Side Bar is now customizable with Custom Tool Panel Components.